# Retirement withdrawal calculator in Microsoft Excel (general formula)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, finance

I am currently trying to create an retirement withdrawal calculator in Microsoft Excel. Does anyone know a general formula that I can use to calculate my monthly withdrawal?

The following variables are given:

Amount saved at the beginning of retirement: *y*

Years of withdrawal: *d*

Rate of return: *i*

Frequency of withdrawals: *monthly*

After *x* years the initial amount should be used up.

*For example:*

Amount saved at the beginning of retirement: 100,000$

Years of withdrawal: 20 years

Rate of return: 5% per year

Frequency of withdrawals: *monthly*

After 20 years the initial amount should be used up.

I would like to calculate how much money I can withdraw per month. Does anyone know a formula behind the common calculators found on the Internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a math/finance question.

Comment: Look into the PMT formula? but that does not take into account Tax Rate.

Comment: Can you post the link to one of these common calculators that you have in mind?

Comment: https://www.minkwealth.com/retirement-withdrawals-calculator/

Comment: https://www.finanzfluss.de/rechner/entnahmeplan/ That's more what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the descriptions are in German.

Comment: Entnahmebetrag = withdrawal amount ; Anlagevermögen = fixed assets ; Zinssatz = interest rate ; Entnahmeintervall = frequency of withdrawals ; Kapitalverzehr = consumption of capital ; Entnahmezeitraum = withdrawal period (I hope this translation helps)

Comment: `=PMT(5%/12,12*20,100000,0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - actually, `=PMT((1+5%)^(1/12)-1,12*20,100000,0)`

Comment: @markfitzpatrick sir, why rate needs to be like this `(1+5%)^(1/12)-1`? because we normally use `5%/12` --> using yours shall give the rate as `0.00407` whereas it with the latter it will be `0.00417`

Comment: Thank you Scott. I just realized that I used the formular incorrectly before.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick if you want the nominal: `=PMT(NOMINAL(0.05,12)/12,12*20,100000,0)`  And that is assuming that the 5% is not the effective rate instead of the nominal.

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya - As the OP does not state the compounding frequency, I would assume it is continuous - thus the monthly rate is `(1+AnnualRate)^(1/PeriodPerYear)-1`. To see this for yourself take `(1+5%/12)^12` and you will arrive at 1.0511, not 1.05. Take 1.00407^12 and you should arrive at about 1.05

Comment: @markfitzpatrick Sir, very helpful. really appreciate, thank you !